# Как конвертировать талицы из Word в JSON?

Tags: python, ms-word

Имеется огромная кипа Word-файлов с таблицами ( около трех сотен ), данные из таблиц надо перенести в БД. В ручную это делать не вариант. Имеются ли какие-то языки программирования, которые могут читать файлы формата `docx`?

До таблицы есть определенное количество символов ("Заседание №N"), которые считывать не надо.

Мне кажется, наиболее удобным способом было бы сконвертировать таблицы в формат JSON.

Таблицы следующего формата:
[image: пример таблицы]

Comment: https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @splash58, помогло, спасибо! Только вот я ошибся с форматом, оказывается все файлы .doc, поэтому немного приходится возиться с конвертацией...